# MySQL default max_connections

Tags: mysql, max, connection

MySQL default max_connections = 151. How many connections should I use for 1000 users per application?

Comment: Depends how often each user connects: if they only connect one after the other, you can get away with 1; if they all connect at once, you'll need 1000 (assuming your application only creates one connection per user).

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if anything, you should probably decrease this number. Do you think that 15% of your users are logged in at the same time and all using the database? That seems like a very high percentage to assume. If your application does not hold on to database connections for more time than needed, then you likely need much less than 150 connections available. As soon as the database communication is done, your app should release the connection. If you are using a connection pool, then openning and closing a connection is very fast.  Using this approach, you can have two users logged in at the same time and it is likely that they will not need more than one connection between them because it is rare that they both are simultaneously executing some DB operation.